# boto detach_volume and unmounting volumes

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto

I am using [boto](http://boto.readthedocs.org) (in Python) to make a small wrapper library for some EC2 / S3 configurations, and wanted to automate the mounting / unmounting process for EC2 volumes. Normally, the procedure is to:

- Attach a volume
- Make a directory on the instance
- Mount the volume to the new directory

Detaching is the same:

- Unmount the volume
- Detach the volume

Boto provides two methods: `attach_volume` and `detach_volume`. I am assuming that `attach_volume` does not automatically mount my filesystem to a directory of my choice, just based on the fact that I can't specify a directory name to mount the device to. But for the [`detach_volume`](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/ec2.html#boto.ec2.connection.EC2Connection.detach_volume), the documentation is ambiguous - if I specify the device through which the volume is exposed, does boto take care of the unmounting for me, therefore safety detaching the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use boto to attach or detach a volume to an ec2 instance, but that's not same as Linux's mount command. It only let the instance know a disk space can be used.

So you need specify a directory name to mount the device in operate system, with mount command, or if you need set lvm partition, depend on your own requirement.

Comment: So I assume that applies for unmounting as well?

Comment: yes, you still need umount in Linux system, and detach in aws.

Answer (score 1):

Boto is simply calling the EC2 API and that does not handle the mounting of your device since that is very OS-dependent.  So, you will need to handle that part separately.